# How can I check if a number is equal to a random number between 1 and the value of the number?

Tags: c#, if-statement, random

I have a variable `phrase.points` that can have a value of between 1 and x.  What I would like to do is something like this:

```
if (phrase.points == random number generated between 1 and x) 
     return;
```

so if:

```
phrase.points == 1 and random number == 1 return
phrase.points == 2 and random number == 1 don't return
phrase.points == 2 and random number == 2 return
phrase.points == 3 and random number == 1 don't return
phrase.points == 3 and random number == 2 don't return
phrase.points == 3 and random number == 3 return
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how could achieve this?

Comment: I'm probably missing something. But what you wrote is just what you wanted. I mean comparing the random number to the `points`.Or are you asking how to generate a random number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Random random = new Random();
int rand = random.Next(1, x + 1);

if (phrase.points > 0 && phrase.points < (rand + 1)) 
     return;
```

Comment: Can you just confirm. If x was equal to 4 then what would be the possible values off rand?

Comment: The parameters of [`Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is the min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)  so if the min = 1 and the max = 4 then the options are: 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2) class, first you would have to create a new Random variable like this:

```
Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
```

Then when you generate a random number do something like this:

```
int randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator.Next(1, x);
```

Where x is your random number (use x + 1 if you want a chance for x to also get generated).

So first you would have to declare a Random, then use it to generate a random number, then compare `phrase.points` to the value generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd= new Random();
int rnd = random.Next(1, x + 1);

var MatchedPoints = phrase.points.Where(x => x == rnd).ToArray();
```